# UIResponder Delays

Tags: iphone, uikit

I have a UIView subclass that overrides UIResponder's touchesMoved: message. I've noticed that when I swipe my finger very quickly across the UIView, my touchesMoved: message only gets called every so often and not constantly getting messaged.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apple Developer Technical Support this is by design.